# Showing Cauchy–Riemann equations in Polar Coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates

I'm taking complex analysis for my math minor and I'm running into trouble with the first problem in the problem set.

> With $x = \cos \theta$, $y = r\sin \theta$, $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan \frac{y}{x}$, show the Cauchy–Riemann equations in polar coordinates by showing the following using the chain rule:
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \cos \theta - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}
> \end{equation}

I know that using the chain rule:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin \theta
\end{equation}

The rest of the set is in the same vein, but I don't really know where to start and am finding myself lost.  How should I begin to tackle this?

Comment: Write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$ same way and solve the system for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. Same with $v$ and then just see what the usual C-R equations give when you substitute

Comment: From my analysis, I think that you are missing a $\sin\theta$ after ${\partial u}/{\partial\theta}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin \theta\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(-r\sin\theta) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} r\cos\theta\tag{2}$$

therefore we can multiply equation $(1)$ by $r\cos\theta$ and equation $(2)$ by $\sin\theta$ to form

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}r\cos\theta =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} r\cos^2 \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} r\cos\theta\sin \theta\tag{3}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(-r\sin^2\theta) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} r\cos\theta\sin\theta\tag{4}$$
from which we can eliminate ${\partial u}/{\partial y}$ by subtracting $(4)$ from $(3)$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}r\cos\theta-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} r\cos^2 \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}r\sin^2\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}r\cos\theta-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} r(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}r\cos\theta-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} r$$
which after dividing by $r$ reduces to the desired form
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\cos\theta-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how did you determine what the function u is?

Comment: $f(z)= u(x, y) +iv(x, y)$ is analytic where $z=x+iy=r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$, then $x(r, \theta)=r\cos\theta$ and $y(r,\theta)=r\sin\theta$.